# extract YQL query content from Javascript response object

Tags: javascript, xpath, yql

I have a javascript using Yql to retrieve a certain text. I success in retrieving the text, but I cannot handle it how I would like to: I can have access to the raw text (without `<br/>`), as you can seen in the obtained object from the debugger:

[image: The object inside the debugger]

by accessing *response.query.results.div.p.content* i have access to the raw text, while the `<br/>`s are excluded (they are uselessly stored inside a br array). How can i obtain the text with the `<br/>`s in the right places?

This is my code (it requires http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.8.0/build/yui/yui-min.js)

```
YUI().use('node', 'event', 'yql', function(Y) {

                    var news_url = 'http://lyrics.wikia.com/Arcade_Fire:Wake_Up';

                    var yql_query = "select * from html where url='" + news_url +"'";
                    yql_query += " and xpath=\"//div[@class='lyricbox']\"";


                    Y.YQL(yql_query, function(response) {
                      if(response.query.results){

                                    /* presentation logic accessing 
                                    to response.query.results.div.p.content */
                       } else{ /* error handling */     }             
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 YUI().use('node', 'event', 'yql', function(Y) {

                var news_url = 'http://lyrics.wikia.com/Arcade_Fire:Wake_Up';

                var yql_query = "select * from html where url='" + news_url +"'";
                yql_query += " and xpath=\"//div[@class='lyricbox']\"";


                Y.YQL(yql_query, function(response) {
                  if(response.query.results){
                     alert(
                      response.query.results.div.p.content.split(' \n ').join('<br />')
                     );

                                /* presentation logic accessing 
                                to response.query.results.div.p.content */
                   } else{ /* error handling */     }             
                });
});
```

not sure what you want to do with the html, so i alert for now...